# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-import

Whenever I run this script under the folder **app/klarna_basic/klarna_basic_test.py**, I always get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'.

The code used for importing is,

```
from app.Fortnox import Fortnox
```

**Fortnox.py** is located in **app(app/Fortnox.py)** folder.

See the image below.

What seems to be problem on this one?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it looks like Fortnox.py is inside the subfolder klarna_basic

```
from klarna_basic.Fortnox import Fortnox
```

or`import klarna_basic.Fortnox`

Comment: Sorry I painted some of the folders. Fortnox.py is outside the **klarna_basic**, it is under the **app** folder, where **klarna_basic** is located as well.